# Failed to build backports.zoneinfo

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker, dockerfile

in terminal I run command `docker build .`, but dockerfile fail to install.

```
 Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/backports
      copying src/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/backports
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_zoneinfo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      running egg_info
      writing src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
      warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_output'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
      writing manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      running build_ext
      building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/lib
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.8 -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
      error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
Failed to build backports.zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have tried many things like:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel
pip install backports.zoneinfo
pip install tzdata
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

None of them helped.
As I have seen in code I don't have gcc. I tried to install. But failed.

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
Python 3.8.10

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: @JanWilamowski it didn't help. It says I already have newest version.

Comment: it needs to be installed inside the container. The exact command will depend on what system the image is based on.

Comment: this link helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942357/cannot-build-python-image-failure-at-pip-install-requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by updating to Ubuntu 22.04. Now I have no issues. I have tried every suggestions on 20.04, but couldn't help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

as @JanWilamowski alluded to. You also need:

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev`.

Then if you try `pip install backports.zoninfo` if should work as expected. It should also be noted that having these installed on your computer is **NOT EQUIVALENT**  to having it installed in the Docker container. Those need to be done separately using Docker compose files.